# Conditional statement always returns false (inline-style)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Conditional statement returns false every time, even if it "should" return true...

```
  const Navy = () => {
    const [content, setContent] = useState(<Today/>)


    const homepage = () => {
      setContent(<Today/>);
    }
    const accountpage = () => {
      setContent(<Account/>);
    }
return(
             <Nav >
                <ul className='menuItems'>
                  <div className='mainmenu'>
                    <Nav.Link className='linkitem' style={{color: content === useState(<Today/>) ?  'red' : 'blue'}}>
                       <li onClick={homepage}> 
                        <i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        Home
                        <div className='arrow'>
                          <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" ></i>
                        </div>
                      </li>
                    </Nav.Link>
                    <Nav.Link className='linkitem' style={{color: content === useState(<Today/>) ?  'red' : 'blue'}}>
                      <li onClick={accountpage}>
                        <i class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        Account
                        <div className='arrow'>
                          <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                        </div>
                      </li>
                    </Nav.Link>
                   </div>
                 <ul/>
              </Nav>
)}
```

My goal is to make this line return true if the component is currently in use (currently returns false regardless):

```
<Nav.Link className='linkitem' style={{color: content === useState(<Today/>) ?  'red' : 'blue'}}>
```

Comment: `useState()` is a hook that returns an array when called at the top level (what it does where you are calling it is hard to say) but its return will never === the value stored in the destructured state variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<Today />` is an istance of your Component: every time you call `<Today />` you create a new, different, object. In any case, you should compare `content`, not `useState(content)`

You can try a tricky (untested) solution like:

```
content.constructor.name === 'Today' ? ...
```

Else, you can change the state as a flag:

```
 const [content, setContent] = useState('today')
```

then, the comparison sure works, and you can choose the render with:

```
content === 'today' ? <Today> : <Account>
```

**But i suggest you a more clean solution** with [React router DOM](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start).

And then:

```
const YourComponent = () => {
const location = useLocation();
... 
return <>
    // when you want to select color
    matchPath(location, {path: '/today'}) ? 'color1' : 'color2'

    // when you choose what component show
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/today">
             <Today>
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/account">
             <Account>
        </Route>
    </Switch>
</>
```

Comment: This was very close! I'll accept the answer for setting me on the right path... instead of content.constructor.name === 'Today' (this returned 'Object'), I used content.type.name

Answer (score 0):

*useState(something)* always gives you an array containing 2 thing

1. value
2. updateFuncion

so you are comparing with value with an array containing [value, updateValueFunction]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2G5P.png)

Added a picture.

If you try to compare the **content** and useState()[0] you still will have some differences to the whole 2 objects.

So still you have to check are the two same check the content.type === useState()[0].type
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCSJO.png)